# How to change button from drop down to manual input python django

Tags: python, html, django, button, django-models

I am making an attendance web app and after I made the relationship of the database one to many, the button changed from manual input to drop down type like so:

[image: web app]

this is my html code:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label for="name">Enter Your Full Name:</label>
            {{form.name}}
            <button type="submit" name="checkName" value="checkName" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

models.py:

```
class employeeName(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee
    
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(employeeName, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeIn = models.TimeField()
    timeOut = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateNewList(forms.ModelForm):
    #name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
```

Comment: Could you include your `form` or `ModelForm`

Comment: @PacketLoss I have added the form.py

Comment: Try `self.fields['name'].widget = TextInput()` in your form class. You will need to import `TextInput()` `django.forms.widgets`

Comment: it says self is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually change the input type of the field in your `ModelForm`.

This may cause issues due to you now needing to check if an employee entered in the text field exists or not.

It may be worth looking into a better way to handle this, such as restricting access to which employees a logged in user can see.

---

```
class CreateNewList(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateNewList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget = TextInput()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
```